# IE7 graphic issue

Tags: css, layout, browser, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7

Guys I need your help to fix IE7 issues with the menu here: luigisettembrini.gov.it

With other browsers the menu looks good and the submenu is over the main menu with a padding.. With IE7 it's not "close" to the menu (it's unusable):
http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/227/senzanomekq.png

Don't know why this happens. I also tried to look with Firebug Lite for IE7 but it's a mess!

Comment: Please post your HTML/CSS/JavaScript code

Comment: Well it's a bit complex because it's a WordPress site (specifically a Twenty Twelve child theme I created), anyway: here's html for nav menu:
http://pastebin.com/7kSrEf6L; here are my css customization related to nav menu over the stock twenty twelve style.css: http://pastebin.com/NHTZTNkf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to find a source for explaining that difference in ie7 but here is a quick fix:

change the nested ul's to have an absolute position of right:0; instead of a left-margin of 200px.

alternatively you could provide a conditional stylesheet for ie7 that gives them a left-margin of zero. but since the uls are already absolutely positioned it will be a pretty easy fix to just remove the margin and add a "right:0;" to the css.

Comment: I applied the quick fix and.. works like a charm! ;))
Really, thank you! I spent hours on this stupid problem (I was even tempted to drop IE7 compatibility).
Now if I can ask you the last favour, the only thing remained is this z-index issue: http://img825.imageshack.us/img825/5024/menuproblem.png
I tried putting a position:relative;z-index:1000 to .main-navigation li ul li, .main-navigation li ul li a, etc with no luck..

Comment: Another issue I am not familiar with. Apparently IE7 and down apply stacking context to elements when other browsers chose not to, long story short each li is beginning a new stack starting at zero.

the only solution i have as of now is to apply a large z-index eg. 999 to the first parent li and then gradually decrease the z-index value for each successive li. 998, 997, 996.. etc. this should fix it for now but i will update you if I figure out a more elegant fix for the problem...     the list items needing the z-index are menu item 248, 249, 250 etc.. not their children